# Trouble connecting Kibana to ElasticSearch on CapRover

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, caprover

Trouble connecting Kibana to ElasticSearch on CapRover

Kibana's error log:

```
unable to revive connection 
no living connections
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the ES port `9200` not being accessible.

So on CapRover go to your ES app; then click on  `App Configs` tab and `Add Port Mapping`: `9200` `9200`

On Kibana's `App Configs` make sure that `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`: `http://srv-captain--<YOUR-ES-APP-ID>:9200`